# Prometheus: What is the minimum value that can be given to storage.tsdb.retention.time flag

Tags: prometheus

I am asked to give minimum value to the storage.tsdb.retention.time for my prometheus. I am giving it as 1d. Can we give value less than this. I mean can we specify time in hours or minutes for this flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but in practice it's not useful to go below a few hours. Disk is cheap.

Comment: if we can specify retention time in hours .If I want to retain the imformation for maximum 5 hours. Should it be given like this?
--storage.tsdb.retention.time=5h
Is this syntax correct?